# An Exception when using rowwise() in eige

Tags: c++, opencv, eigen

i'm new in `eigen`. my entries in `OpenCV` form and i have to use `Map` class such that convert them to `eigen` form. I've written following code:

```
int main()
{
    Mat label_data, train_data;
    //some code
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1>> train_data_in_Eigen(train_data.ptr<double>(), train_data.rows, train_data.cols);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1>>* pTrain_data_in_Eigen = &train_data_in_Eigen;
    foo(train_labels, pTrain_data_in_Eigen);
    //some code
}
void foo(std::vector<int> gnd, Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1>>* pdata)
{
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 1>> _data = *pdata;
    auto meanOf_data = _data.colwise().mean();
    _data.rowwise() -= meanOf_data;
    //some code
}
```

I've got this `Exception Error` in line `_data.rowwise() -= meanOf_data;` :
`Exception thrown at: Access violation reading location`. but when I've written in this way: `auto dd = _data.rowwise() -= meanOf_data` i didn't have an `Exception`. what's problem? and how to fix?

Comment: Generally, try to provide a [mcve] which actually compiles and reproduces the error. Your MCVE won't compile and does not even include a `rowwise`.

Answer (score 2):

Because of `auto`, `meanOf_data` is an expression referencing dead temporary objects, not an actual vector. Read [common pitfalls](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). Solutions:

```
RowVectorXd meanOf_data = _data.colwise().mean();
```

or:

```
auto meanOf_data = _data.colwise().mean().eval();
```

Comment: thanks, but by your first way: `VectorXd meanOf_data = _data.colwise().mean();` I got this error: `YOU_PASSED_A_COLUMN_VECTOR_BUT_A_ROW_VECTOR_WAS_EXPECTED` 
then i tried by `RowVectorXd meanOf_data = _data.colwise().mean();` and with your second way, i got the exception error that i mentioned in above question.

Comment: You are right for `RowVectorXd`, but I cannot reproduce your issue even within a memory debugger. So please provide a (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. Your issue likely come from somewhere else.